# How to increase the count of the append div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having quite problem on this one. I want to increase the count but it doesn't increase. The count starts at 3 in the name of my div the output will be: 'faq[3][question]' but the problem is, it does not increment. what i want to happen is every time i add new div it will become. faq[3][question], faq[4][question], so on and so for. I hope you guys can help me

```
import  app  from '../app.setup';

app.dynamicField = class extends app.Component {
onReady() {
    var wrapper = $(".container");
    var add_button = $(".btn-question");
    var count = 3;
    var _titleQuestion = 'faq["' + count + '"][question]';
    var _titleAnswer = 'faq["' + count + '"][answer]';

    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="question form-control mb-3" name="' + _titleQuestion +'"  placeholder="Question"/><textarea class="form-control answer" name="' + _titleAnswer + '" placeholder="Answer"></textarea></div><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>');
            count++;
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        count--;
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide **all relevant code**.  We don't know what your HTML looks like.  I recommend reading [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't think you need to look to html code

Comment: Well I hope you get an answer.  I won't be answering it because without HTML i can't test my solution to your requirements.  The reason that link exists to begin with it to help *you* get more answers because many people don't want to reverse engineer your code to built html (including me) so we can debug it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click handler function does not have any affect on the modified `count` variable.

You should update the variable inside the click event handler function:

```
..........
$(add_button).click(function(e) {
    var _titleQuestion = 'faq["' + count + '"][question]';
    var _titleAnswer = 'faq["' + count + '"][answer]';
    e.preventDefault();
    $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="question form-control mb-3" name="' + _titleQuestion +'"  placeholder="Question"/><textarea class="form-control answer" name="' + _titleAnswer + '" placeholder="Answer"></textarea></div><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>');
    count++;
});

$(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    var _titleQuestion = 'faq["' + count + '"][question]';
    var _titleAnswer = 'faq["' + count + '"][answer]';
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    count--;
});
...........
```